# c# using advanced datagridview (ADGV) filter without BindingSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, filtering

I am using the advanced DataGridView (ADGV) found [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=adgv) to add filtering capabilities to my application.

The code for filtering or sorting is mentioned as:

```
private void advancedDataGridView1_SortStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.stockHistoryBindingSource.Sort = advancedDataGridView1.SortString;
}

private void advancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.stockHistoryBindingSource.Filter = advancedDataGridView1.FilterString;
}
```

But I can't use this because in my project I am reading an XML file and binding it to my ADGV with this code:

```
void QueryFoos()
{
    IEnumerable<FooViewData> query =
        from foo in XmlFiles.FOO.Root.Descendants("foo")
        select new FooViewData
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(foo.Attribute("id").Value),
            Num = Convert.ToInt32(foo.Attribute("num").Value),
            ...
        };

    advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = query.OrderBy(n => n.ID).ThenBy(r => r.Num).ToList();
}
```

I tried a code like this but I am not surprised that it is throwing exception in my face:

```
BindingSource x = (BindingSource)this.advancedDataGridView1.DataSource;
x.Filter = advancedDataGridView1.FilterString;
this.advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = x;
```

Is there some work around to use the filtering and sorting of the ADGV ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out I had this same problem today and was looking for solutions.  Basically the problem is that ADGV was written to be used with a DataTable and not a list of objects.

This solution works for me however your mileage may vary.

What I ended up doing was using [dynamic linq](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) to perform the filter on the list of objects myself. The hack part was me converting the filter string that ADGV produces and converting it to a string that dynamic linq expects.

We start with some data.  I have a class named DataPointGridViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class DataPointGridViewModel 
{
    public int DataPointId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool InAlarm { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public double ScalingMultiplier { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The data could be anything. This is the data that you will be filtering on in the grid.  Obviously you will have your own data class. You need to replace this DataPointGridViewModel clas with your own model/data object.

Now, here is the code example code you need to add. I have also got a sample project on github here: I have a working version of this code on github: [here](https://github.com/OceanAirdrop/AdvancedDataGridViewDataModel)

Here is the code you need to add:

```
List<DataPointGridViewModel> m_dataGridBindingList = null;
List<DataPointGridViewModel> m_filteredList = null;

private void dataGridView2_FilterStringChanged(object sender, Zuby.ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView.FilterEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView2.FilterString) == true )
        {
            m_filteredList = m_dataGridBindingList;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = m_dataGridBindingList;
        }
        else
        {
            var listfilter = FilterStringconverter(dataGridView2.FilterString);

            m_filteredList = m_filteredList.Where(listfilter).ToList();

            dataGridView2.DataSource = m_filteredList;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
}
```

And this is the function to convert the ADGV filter string to the Dynamic Linq filter string:

```
private string FilterStringconverter(string filter)
{
    string newColFilter = "";

    // get rid of all the parenthesis 
    filter = filter.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");

    // now split the string on the 'and' (each grid column)
    var colFilterList = filter.Split(new string[] { "AND" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    string andOperator = "";

    foreach (var colFilter in colFilterList)
    {
        newColFilter += andOperator;

        // split string on the 'in'
        var temp1 = colFilter.Trim().Split(new string[] { "IN" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        // get string between square brackets
        var colName = temp1[0].Split('[', ']')[1].Trim();

        // prepare beginning of linq statement
        newColFilter += string.Format("({0} != null && (", colName);

        string orOperator = "";

        var filterValsList = temp1[1].Split(',');

        foreach (var filterVal in filterValsList)
        {
            // remove any single quotes before testing if filter is a num or not
            var cleanFilterVal = filterVal.Replace("'", "").Trim();

            double tempNum = 0;
            if (Double.TryParse(cleanFilterVal, out tempNum))
                newColFilter += string.Format("{0} {1} = {2}", orOperator, colName, cleanFilterVal.Trim());
            else
                newColFilter += string.Format("{0} {1}.Contains('{2}')", orOperator, colName, cleanFilterVal.Trim());

            orOperator = " OR ";
        }

        newColFilter += "))";

        andOperator = " AND ";
    }

    // replace all single quotes with double quotes
    return newColFilter.Replace("'", "\"");
}
```

...and finally the sort function looks like this:

```
private void dataGridView2_SortStringChanged(object sender, Zuby.ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView.SortEventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView2.SortString) == true)
            return;

        var sortStr = dataGridView2.SortString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView2.FilterString) == true)
        {
            // the grid is not filtered!
            m_dataGridBindingList = m_dataGridBindingList.OrderBy(sortStr).ToList();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = m_dataGridBindingList;                    
        }
        else
        {
            // the grid is filtered!
            m_filteredList = m_filteredList.OrderBy(sortStr).ToList();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = m_filteredList;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need the Dynamic Linq library from [here](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)

You can use Nuget to bring it into your project:

```
Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic
```

Comment: I suspected that and it seems you are right I will try checking the code. Thanks

Comment: hey @Tima.  Just to let you know I have updated the "FilterStringconverter" code above to my latest version (just some small tweaks)

Comment: I get error for "DataPointGridViewModel" not defined. Can I know what needs to be done?

Comment: Hi @Programmer.  For reference, I have a working version of this here: https://github.com/OceanAirdrop/AdvancedDataGridViewDataModel  - The DataPointGridviewModel will just be your data that you want displaying..

Comment: DataPointGridViewModel what is that exactly?

Comment: DataPointGridViewModel is your model object. The data. So if your DataGridView is displaying a list of people List<People>(), then replace DataPointGridViewModel with your People class.  I have also updated my answer to show this.

Comment: @OceanAirdrop hey, i hope i'm not bothing you but you seem quite knowledgeable when it comes to using ADGV. i was wondering if you could help me with an issue i am having. Made a Reddit post for it. https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/12jexr4/advanced_datagridview_filter_help_requested/ i would really appreciate any input :)

Comment: Hi @A.bakker - I've not used ADGV for quite some time now but regardless, I just went to your link and there is no question to answer.  The post just has a title! - Not sure if its been deleted maybe? Perhaps you should re-post the question there and also here on SO here so that someone can help you.

Comment: @OceanAirdrop Thanks for your reply, but i managed to solve it. The issue was that the Filter Checkboxes disappear if you check them (so you can't cancel a filter) but reverting back to an older version (1.1.25515.10 to be precise) fixes it :)  Seems newer versions are just buggy.

Comment: @A.bakker Ahh I see, thats great stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
    DataTable OrignalADGVdt = null;
    private void advancedDataGridView1_FilterStringChanged(object sender, Zuby.ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView.FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        Zuby.ADGV.AdvancedDataGridView fdgv = advancedDataGridView1;
        DataTable dt = null;
        if (OrignalADGVdt == null)
        {
            OrignalADGVdt = (DataTable)fdgv.DataSource;
        }
        if (fdgv.FilterString.Length > 0)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)fdgv.DataSource;
        }
        else//Clear Filter
        {
            dt = OrignalADGVdt;
        }

        fdgv.DataSource = dt.Select(fdgv.FilterString).CopyToDataTable();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please avoid posting code only answers and provide some explanation with your code for more clarification. code only answers can not be considered as acceptable ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here follow my code sample for filter advanced datagrid

```
string myFilter = "(Convert([myCol],System.String) IN ('myfilter'))"
dg.LoadFilterAndSort(myFilter, "");
```

and to clear filter

```
dg.CleanFilter();
```

Comment: What does this do? You might need more details in your answer.