# using advanced datagrid view (ADGV) with a list of objects

Tags: c#, datagridview, filtering

I am using the advanced DataGridView (ADGV) found here to add filtering capabilities to my application.
i am trying to use it to a list of objects, i found a solution that can help do that in this link 
[c# using advanced datagridview (ADGV) filter without BindingSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709414/c-sharp-using-advanced-datagridview-adgv-filter-without-bindingsource)

but my Visual studio doesn't recognise the "DataPointGridViewModel" class used in the solution 
help me plelase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<DataPointGridViewModel>` is a List of class objects and the class is presumably one of the answer's. It could just as easily have been `List<string>`.

An alternative would be to convert the List to a DataTable which is what I use with the AdvancedDataGridView. There's a Microsoft extension method to do just that so no extra code required on your part [DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
// Get data and set the DataSources
List<MyClass> result = // get your list
this.MyBindingSource.DataSource = result.CopyToDataTable();
this.Adgv.DataSource = this.myBindingSource;

...

// Event handlers to make the sort/filter actually happen
private void Adgv_FilterStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyBindingSource.Filter = this.Adgv.FilterString;
}

private void Adgv_SortStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyBindingSource.Sort = this.Adgv.SortString;
}
```