# I need to filter my DataGridView with selected column

Tags: c#, winforms, ssms

I'm developing a generic `SQLManipulator` with `Windows` `Forms`. I need to `Filter` my `columns` but I don't know how to convert:

```
private void AdvancedDataGridView_FilterStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       this.customerBindingSource.Sort = this.advancedDataGridView.SortStrings;
  }
```

That's not my code I watched it from that [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaZeeHRRCGA). My application is not connected with DB. I have login form that when you enter server Name you get a `combobox` with DB names and than you are transferred to the next form, choose `table` here, and `datagridview` is populated.

That's how my form looks like:
[image]
But everytime the column will be with different names?
I'm not really sure what should I do here?

And do I need to convert `customerBindingSource`, or I should do something else?

Comment: The best way is "NOT: to filter the DGV.  Use a SQL DataAdapter and fill a datatable (dataset).  Then filter the table.  To Add data to the DGV use datagridview1.DataSource = dt where dt is the datatable.

Comment: if you mean something like this:
 BindingSource x = (BindingSource)this.advancedDataGridView.DataSource;
 x.Filter = advancedDataGridView.SortString;
 his.advancedDataGridView.DataSource = x;
it throws an exception :)

Comment: A DGV you have an option of either using a BindingSource or just using a datasource.  Your filter may be null which is creating the error.  I usually create a new datatable for my filters DataTable dt1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => some filter).CopyToDataTable();  Check in TaskManager you do not get a memory leak.  I usually set "dt1 = null" before filling a second time so a memory leak doesn't occur.  I've been working with a 6GB datatable and found using x86 mode caused a Out Of Memory Exception.  Going to 64 bit mode got rid of exception.

Comment: I'm not able to use that, I need some other solution, using ADGV nuget package.

Comment: Then include as part of Tags description.  Using a 3rd party library makes a big difference on the answer.  See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709414/c-sharp-using-advanced-datagridview-adgv-filter-without-bindingsource

Comment: I really don't get what is that DataPointGridViewModel  :)

Comment: It is a class in the ADGV nuget package.  You need to understand the 3rd party library before you start to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do this by using **BindingSource**

Filter columns

```
    private void AdvancedDataGridView_FilterStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
            source1.DataSource = AdvancedDataGridView.DataSource;

            AdvancedDataGridView.DataSource = source1;
            source1.Filter = AdvancedDataGridView.FilterString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Sorting columns

```
    private void AdvancedDataGridView_SortStringChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
            source1.DataSource = AdvancedDataGridView.DataSource;

            AdvancedDataGridView.DataSource = source1;
            source1.Sort = AdvancedDataGridView.SortString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Hope it's help.